# How to configure ADFS 3.0 so that a claim containing the NetBIOS name is included?

Tags: adfs

Is there any way to configure ADFS 3.0 so that it returns a claim containing the NetBIOS name of the user?

To interop with legacy systems, I need the subject name in NT4 format (i.e. `SamAccountName\NetBiosName`)

Right now, the only way I could figure out was a little hacky: include the domain-qualified groups, find the one called "MYDOMAIN\Domain Users", and strip off everything after the backslash.

There has to be a better way, right?

Comment: I'm afraid not . Based on my understanding , if you use a domain account to get authentication ,you will get a user name with syntax 'domain\user' to identify the user uniquely .